# Redundant Paths between DELL R720 and MD3420 in ESXi 5.5

Tags: vmware-esxi, dell, sas, hba

We had some trouble configuring redundant paths between a DELL R720 and MD3420 storage connected via two LSI 12GB SAS-HBAs using ESXi 5.5. The datastore was accessible and worked fine, except for the redundancy (the datatstore was only accessible over one of both paths).

We found a workaround together with DELL support, which included removing VMwares default driver and downloading a newer version of the driver:

- esxcli system module set –enabled=false –module=lsi-msgpt3
- Download driver from: https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?downloadGroup=DT-ESXI5X-LSI-SAS-MPT3SAS-050000001VMW&productId=285
- esxcli software vib install -v {VIBFILE}

This solution works fine since then, no problems occured.

My question is:
Does anybody know, if this procedure will be still requierd with a new R730 we are deploying this week?

We want to individualize the installation as little as possible, for the obvious reason of troubleshooting the system in the future and we dont want to provoke any issues regarding compatibility between 2 servers connecting to the datastore using different drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked like a charm using the fully patched ESXi 5.5
It doesnt seem like the workaround is still necessary.

Apreciate the thoughts on this topic, though. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you've installed the latest ESXi (5.5u2d as of this moment) plus all available critical and recommended patched (very easy with VCUM) and you still need to install this driver to get MP working then yes you will need to use it for other identical system. That said if you aren't 100% sure you're 100% up to date then just do that on the next build, i.e. without the extra driver and if everything works then great, if not then you're going to need to deploy it - though it would be easiest to add it to your VCUM rather than applying it manually.